# WinForms Multiple Charts with Slider

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to create a Form that has multiple Charts.
The Charts have different data.
I want to have the options with a slider to show each part of the Charts.
The starting position of the Charts should be the same. Which means when I slide the First Slider it should show the Chart1 and then the remaining part of Chart2 and so on for the others.
A good example of what I want to achieve is this example with a slider for two photos, but I want to implement multiple Charts:

https://web-toolbox.dev/en/tools/image-compare-slider

How it should look:

[image]

I tried with a splitter but it has two panels and the charts should overlap or have the same position

Comment: Without using a 3rd party control, this will be impossible to manipulate an actual image in such a way.  You would have to manually change the widths to immitate this behavior.  Not impossible, but i don't think it will be easy to make it look super nice, if you're ok with a mediocre outcome than perhaps you can attempt it.

Comment: Capture the charts as images. Then display them in a Single PictureBox and override the Paint() event; draw just portions of them as rectangles with a vertical "slider" drawn on top. Hit-test to see if the mouse is over a "slider",  and if they're dragging. Use an overload of [DrawImage()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.drawimage?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0#system-drawing-graphics-drawimage(system-drawing-image-system-drawing-rectangle-system-int32-system-int32-system-int32-system-int32-system-drawing-graphicsunit)) that allows you to draw just a portion.